# Why are accented passing tones not figured but suspensions are?

Tags: ornaments, figured-bass

If 4-3 happens as a suspension and it is figured then why not also figure an accented passing tone 4-3?

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that there are plenty of times where accented passing tones *are* shown in the figures. The most common example of this would be with the cadential six-four, where the sixth and fourth above the bass are understood as accented non-chord tones (often passing tones) that delay the appearance of the fifth and third above the bass.

Answer (score 2):

When you decide an accented passing tone is a suspension, figure it.  When you decide a suspension is merely an accented passing tone, don’t figure it.

If you are figuring for analysis, your choice.  If you are figuring for a continuo player to read, I suggest you err on the side of figuring.  It will help them play less clunkers.

Comment: Pretty roundabout way to argue that accented passing tones *are* figured. Richard's answer provided that argument a lot more clearly.

Comment: We're not really making the same point.  Richard's answer confuses the issue by relying on the example of a cadential 6/4, which is a very special case where two notes MAY be considered accented passing notes (or an unprepared suspension) but are by no means universally accepted as such.